# Python Dual Encoding

Tags: python, encoding, tcp, decode

I have a piece of code that I convert to `cp1252` 
and the thing is, it doesnt seem like 1252 supports all the characters unless somehow I am just doing this all wrong I send code to a box recieve it back and the convert it.. it works sometimes if the characters are supported but if they are not then it wont convert it for some odd reason if anyone has an idea whats wrong that would be great.

```
def ByteToHex( byteStr ):

    return ' '.join( [ "%02X" % ord( x ) for x in byteStr ] )


def HexToByte( hexStr ):

    bytes = []

    hexStr = ''.join( hexStr.split(" ") )

    for i in range(0, len(hexStr), 2):
    bytes.append( chr( int (hexStr[i:i+2], 16 ) ) )

    return ''.join( bytes ).encode(encoding='cp1252', errors='strict')


def sockCon ():
    global HOST
    global PORT
    global TX

    TX = b"\x7E\x00\x0C\x01\x00\xA5\xBD\x00\x7E\x01\x00\x40\x2D\x00\x3F\x71"

    T_X = 'TX = '
    R_X = 'RX = '

    BUFFER = 8192

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    b = 1
    while b == 1:
        s.send(TX)        
        time.sleep(1)

        __ByteStr2 = s.recv(BUFFER)
        print (__ByteStr2)

        xxString = __ByteStr2[16:-2].decode('cp1252')
        __bytStr = ByteToHex(xxString)
        print (__bytStr)

        listStr = "".join(__bytStr)


        print (listStr)
        print ("Something is ", struct.unpack('!d', HexToByte(listStr)))
```

So after the code runs I would get stuff like this...

If the code works and the characters are supported then it looks something like this..

```
b'~\x00\x16\x81\xa5\xbd3\x02~\x00\x01\xc7-\n\x00\x11@ivfffff\x90\xac'
40 69 76 66 66 66 66 66
40 69 76 66 66 66 66 66
Something is (203.7,)
```

However if the characters are not supported then it looks something like this.

```
b'~\x00\x16\x81\xa5\xbd4\x02~\x00\x01\xc7-\n\x00#@\r\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9aa\x01'
40 0D 2122 2122 2122 2122 2122 161
40 0D 2122 2122 2122 2122 2122 161
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ecunningham\Desktop\Python Projects\Test\main\hello.py", line 78, in <module>
sockCon()
File "C:\Users\ecunningham\Desktop\Python Projects\Test\main\hello.py", line     76, in sockCon
print ("The Display Value is", struct.unpack('!d', HexToByte(listStr)))
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8
```

Comment: Why do you use `decode`?

Comment: so I can use the ByteToHex method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm guys I fixed my problem seems that cp1252 has Unicode characters in its decoding table and all I had to do was remove them and put hex values from \x80 all the way up too 9F